# how to show UIAlertView on the top of the keyboard?

Tags: ios, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I have a TextField that currently have the focus and the **keyboard is visible**. I want now to show an alert on the top of the screen (`UIAlertView`) but this cause the keyboard to close. is their any way to show the `UIAlertView` **on the top of the keyboard** ?

Comment: What are you using, `UIAlertView` or `UIAlertController` to show the alert?

Comment: right now UIAlertView but i think it's the same with UIAlertControler no ?

Comment: The two shows an alert, but `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8

Comment: yes i know but i don't want to update my code right now, i just want to see how to make the alert on the top of the keyboard ...